# Set UITableView frame according to Tapku calendar height

Tags: iphone, ios, calendar

I am having Tapku calendar and table view below it. The calendar does not have static height it depends on number of rows in it, that differs for various months. Like for some months there are 5 rows in it and for some 6 rows. I want to set the table frame, that it should starts from where the calendar ends. I tried the way mentioned below but doesn't work.

```
- (void)calendarMonthView:(TKCalendarMonthView *)monthView monthDidChange:(NSDate *)d {
NSLog(@"calendarMonthView monthDidChange:%@",d);

  [self.mTableView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, calendar.frame.origin.y + calendar.frame.size.height, 320, 308 - calendar.frame.size.height - calendar.frame.origin.y)];
  [self.mTableView reloadData];

NSLog(@"calendar height:%f", calendar.frame.size.height);
}
```

It is printing calendar height:0.000000  in console.
Please guide for above.

Answer (score 1):

If this is still relevant for you, try this from the TKCalendarMonthTableViewController.m file in the TapkuLibrary under UI>Calendar>Month, it worked for me, I had the exact same issue as you:

```
- (void)calendarMonthView:(TKCalendarMonthView *)monthView monthDidChange:(NSDate *)month animated:(BOOL)animated {
    [self updateTableOffset:animated];
}

- (void) updateTableOffset:(BOOL)animated{

    if(animated){
        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.4];
        [UIView setAnimationDelay:0.1];
    }


    float y = self.monthView.frame.origin.y + self.monthView.frame.size.height;
    self.tableView.frame = CGRectMake(self.tableView.frame.origin.x, y, self.tableView.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height - y );
    if(animated) [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

To adjust the height from the beginning, on loadView, I just selected the date after initializing the calendar:

```
calendar =  [[TKCalendarMonthView alloc] initWithSundayAsFirst:NO];
[calendar selectDate:[NSDate date]];
```

That way the frame isn't only adjusted after monthDidChange..

hope it helped!